# Two layer if condition

Tags: python

I try my best to explain what I need:

```
If len(x) > 5:
   sample = func_sample(5)
   If sample meet conditionA:
      Then use sample
   Else go to elif bellow
Elif len(x) > 4:
   sample = func_sample(4)
   if sample meet conditionA:
      Then use sample
   Else go the else bellow
Else:
   sample = func_sample(3)
```

I know in VBA there is option `goto` but not in Python, so I am a bit struggling here

Comment: It would really help if we knew an example input(s) and expected output(s) for this to help make sense

Comment: You’re probably looking at logic like this: start by setting `sample` to `None`. Check if len is over 4. If so, decide if the parameter to `func_sample` should be 4 or 5. Get the result of `func_sample`. If it satisfies your condition, assign it to `sample`. End of this condition branch. Now check if `sample` is still `None` or not. If it is, do your last fall through case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? (assuming you actually also use the sample in the last case...)

```
def get_sample(L):
    if L > 5:
       sample = func_sample(5)
       if conditionA(sample):
           return sample
    if L > 4:
       sample = func_sample(4)
       if conditionA(sample):
           return sample
    return func_sample(3)

sample = get_sample(len(x))
use_sample(sample)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It solves the problem. I didn't figure it is that easy by removing the Elif and using IF.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest Julien's answer but if you don't want to make a function this will do the same thing but just hoping this makes it make sense if theirs didn't already:

```
sample = None

if len(x) > 5:
   new_sample = func_sample(5)
   if conditionA(new_sample):
      sample = new_sample

if len(x) > 4:
   new_sample = func_sample(4)
   if conditionA(new_sample):
      sample = new_sample

if sample is None:
    sample = func_sample(3)
```

Comment: Depending on what `func_sample` does, you might not want to call it more often than necessary…

Comment: @Jab: Thank you for your help. I agree with @deceze it would be efficient to put a dummy variable to indicate if the previous condition is met and we don't have to execute unnecessary commands afterward. Something like `if len(x) > 4 and meet_previous_condition == False`

Answer (score 1):

The `:=` assignment expression operator offers a new way to solve this problem, by turning the nested `if` statements into a single conditional statement that *also* assigns to `sample`.

```
if len(x) > 5 and conditionA(sample := func_sample(5)):
   use(sample)
elif len(x) > 4 and conditionA(sample := func_sample(4)):
   use2(sample)
else:
   use3(sample := func_sample(3))
```